# What use does horse poop have?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I have recently acquire the ability to command my D-horse to poop wherever I'm pleased.

I'm wondering what use can that have. Is there something useful I can do with this ability?

Comment: I don't know if you are alive or if you where caputed by the enemy, but if you are still with us, accept the answer!

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry, first time around the app

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The horse poop can make vehicles spin out of control if they drive over it, which also incapacitates the driver (and passenger) for a short time.

Here's a video showing it in action:

Answer (score 0):

If you position the horse near a guard, throw a magazine by the horse or have the guard notice you to prompt him to walk toward the horse. If you make the horse poop in front of the guard, they become visibly disgusted and you can sneak up to them or walk past them as well.

Comment: "position the horse near a guard": do you mean still mounted on the horse or is there another way?